# Android UI - Android horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Are there any samples similar to this? Android horizontal scroll view... Or how can I go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to have a look at these:

- [Sample](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/tag/android-development/)
- [Sample2](http://bloggers.com/posts/android-coding-22196/page2)

Comment: Hmmmm....i have already seen this example..but this uses the Gallery class...which is better to use Gallery or HorizontalScrollView ?

Comment: According to me its better to use the `GalleryView` than `HorizontalScrollView`.. Its my suggestion.. U better go what suits for u arun.

Comment: I'm really lost. What we can use in place of GalleryView? A GridView with custom numColumn based at screen size, inside of HorizontalScrollView?

Answer (score 14):

Pseudo:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Image1 />
            <Image2 />
            <Image3 />
            <Image4 />
            <Image5 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button1 android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button2 android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button3 android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button4 android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout>
```

Have fun!