# Horizontal slider bar in android

Tags: android

I want to create a horizontal slider bar which slides right and left according to the corresponding button click. I have attached image below for reference.....

[image]

I want to create the thing which is encircled in blue area. I which the right arrow shows, used to slide the bar in right side with different items and information shows below according to selected item on the horizontal bar. I have searched enough on web but nothing finds as similar as above. Please suggest me for the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just have a look at the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237566/text-gallery-on-android. Its definetly the thing you need.

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565949/android-ui-android-horizontal-scroll-view

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Gallery View instead of Horizontal Scroll View [check the example :](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/09/custom-adapter-on-both-gridview-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just slider bar, I suppose, you can use Gallery widget.

Comment: Hi sver  i have a query regarding your reply , how to scroll gallery widget on next and previous button click?