# Click to scroll in Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android

I want to scroll multiple items in `Horizontal scroll view` on the click of `left` and `right` arrow click which are resided in both corners. Means I have a `Horizontal scroll view` with two buttons left and right for scrolling items according to the same. I have searched enough on web but nothing matched. Please suggest me for the right solution regarding the same.

Comment: what have you tried ? The previous question posted by you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206259/horizontal-slider-bar-in-android was almost same. You got various correct comments and answers but you didn't reply to even single answer or comment. Seems you havent tried anything.. I AM NOT ATTRACTED TO ANSWER YOUR QUESTION really...

Comment: Hello Kartik, all answers posted in that questions are not so correct, because I am trying the same according to them since morning but results remains same. It is achieved only through Horizontal Scroll View......and I implemented also but I am failed to scroll the view on button click that's why I posted this question. If you don't want to give the answer then I am not forcing you to do like same.

Comment: If you are facing problem in implementation, you should have commented on the answers that you have tried. I dont think you need a separate question. And again, for what COMMENT sections are there!

Comment: Kartik, Please read this question carefully, this is totally different question from the previous one. And its my decision that where to comment or where not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kartik for your valuable time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yourScrollView.scrollTo(x, y);` in the button listener method. Add further conditions to limit the ends or to make it infinitely scrollable.

Go through the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) for more info...

Answer (score 0):

just set focus on next child, by using following methods:

```
`viewGroup.findFocus();
```

to get View which is focused,

and getNext vuew from layout and set focus on that view by:

```
view.requestFocus();
```