# Android: HorizontalScrollView with images loaded from database

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android UI - Android horizontal scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565949/android-ui-android-horizontal-scroll-view)

I couldn't find a solution on how to create `HorizontalScrollView` with images that are loaded from `database` as `BLOB`. I would like to create something like `Gallery` but I can't use `Gallery` widget because I want multiple selection of items. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Here is a link for an implementation of Horizontal ListView https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android. It might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Andro! I think it'll be the best solution how to solve my problem. Thank you again.